# Return setState in reduce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, reduce

I have a state that returns an array of objects :

```
const [coins, setCoins] = useState([])
const [newCoins, setNewCoins] = useState([])

console.log(coins)

[
  {
    "note": "",
    "quantity ": 2,
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "price": 37000.98,
  },
  {
    "note": "",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 37000.98,
  },
  {
    "note": "",
    "name": "Ethereum",
    "price": 2690.32,
    "quantity": 1,
  }
]
```

I would like, starting from this list of objects, to create a new table in order to display a concise summary of the previous table. So you have to merge the objects with the same "name", cumul the "quantity", and finally add a new "key" which will be used to add the current price (retrieved via an API).

Using reduce works fine and returns me a new array

```
const coinsArrCopy = coins.map(item => ({...item}))
  const coinsCopy = coinsArrCopy.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    let existItem = acc.find(item => item.name === obj.name);
    if (existItem) {
      existItem.quantity += obj.quantity
      delete existItem.price
      delete existItem.note
      return acc;
    }
    acc.push({...obj, currentPrice: 0})
    // return setNewCoins(acc) <== ERROR
    return acc;
 }, [])
```

The new table looks like this:

```
console.log(coinsCopy)

[
  {
    "quantity": 3,
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "currentPrice": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Ethereum",
    "quantity": 1,
    "currentPrice": 0
  }
]
```

How to transfer this `coinsCopy` array to `newCoins` state? `return setNewCoins(acc)` gives me an error `setNewCoins is not a function`?

Comment: Where are you performing this transformation? And declare separate state for the transformed array: `const [newCoins, setNewCoins] = useState([])`

Comment: This state is declared in the same place as my other states. I edited my comment to add it

Answer (score -1):

You can call your `setNewCoins` function to update the state right after you've created the `coinsCopy` variable, as long as you're performing such calculation on the same component or on a child component (in this case you'll have to pass the `setNewCoins` function through props). You'll end up with something like:

```
const coinsArrCopy = coins.map(item => ({...item}))
const coinsCopy = coinsArrCopy.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    let existItem = acc.find(item => item.name === obj.name);
    if (existItem) {
      existItem.quantity += obj.quantity
      delete existItem.price
      delete existItem.note
      return acc;
    }
    acc.push({...obj, currentPrice: 0})
    return acc;
 }, [])

//This will update the state with the current value of the coinsCopy array.
setNewCoins(coinsCopy)
```

Comment: Of course I tried. This doesn't work and returns the error: TypeError: setNewCoins is not a function

Comment: Please, provide more context. Share more code if possible, that would let us know if you're calling the function on the same component, on a child component or something along those lines.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was actually quite simple.

You have to add the change of state in a useEffect, and listen to the "coins" state to restart the effect again when it detects a change.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setNewCoins(coinsCopy)
}, [coins])
```